# Merge multiple geometry lines into a single geometry line

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Now I have 3 lines (LINESTRING) with 3 different geometry values.

```
Line#1 : "11AABB"
Line#2 : "22CCDD"
Line#3 : "33EEFF"
```

How to merge these lines into a single line via PostGIS function ?

I use to know that It use [ST_LineMerge](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) or [ST_Union](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Union.html) But I'm not sure how to use it with geometry values.

Answer (score 1):

could you be more specific?

with the examples you provided you could try this:

```
SELECT ST_Union('11AABB'::geometry , ST_Union('22CCDD'::geometry,'33EEFF'::geometry ) );
```

your geometry values are invalid, but this is the correct sintax of the query you want. You should get this error with the example you provided: "ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry"